# Password authentication takes forever on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, passwords, ubuntu-16.04, login-screen, lock-screen

I must clarify that it's not about SSH! So please don't mark it as duplicate, it's probably not!

It's the simple login on Ubuntu that is taking forever, be it just after boot or on a lockscreen or sudo-promt on the terminal, it takes a few minutes to process the password I enter. I have been noticing this the past few days and I don't remember of making any big changes like upgrade or anything. The only thing I remember is changing the /etc/krb5.conf a few days ago.

[checkout this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEzLo.jpg)

Thanks very much.

Edit:

### Kerberos Conf file:

### [/etc/krb5.conf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1upYTa03U5bthoPwNWjCmXS-UPk0WfgBS)

Comment: *The only thing I remember is changing the /etc/krb5.conf* (...) and you say it like that's nothing or unimportant. But it's probably the cause. What exactly have you changed (and why)?

Comment: Post your krb5.conf if you want help.  Won’t have to worry about this question being closed as a duplicate just “too broad”. Tell us about your Kerberos realm.

Comment: Ok, I will post my krb5.conf, I updated this with Fermilab version.

Comment: I have updated the question with the krb5.conf file